# Prove that the sequence converges to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that the sequence {$\frac{n}{2^n}$} converges to zero. I am not able to find the number that n must be greater then to proceed with the proof.

Comment: `proceed with the proof` It helped if you showed where you got stuck, so it would be easier to understand the difficulty, and suggest how to proceed.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{2^n}=2-2^{-(m-1)}-2^{-m}m$ so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$ converges (to $2$) and $\frac{n}{2^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Guest the OP is talking only about sequences, not series.

Comment: how would I be able to compare it with the sequence {1/n} for the proof?

Comment: would i do something like 1/n > n/2^n > 0 for n>4 ? but then how to apply squeeze theorem for proof

Comment: Look at ILoveMath's answer below for a simple way to show it.

Answer (score 2):

To prove $\frac{n}{2^n} \to 0 $, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we must cock up an $N > 0$ so that if $n \geq N$, then $| \frac{n}{2^n} | < \epsilon $.

We start bounding $\frac{n}{2^n}$. Notice for large enough $n$, we have $2^n > n^2 $, thus ,

$$ \left| \frac{n }{2^n } \right| < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} $$

Thus, if we select $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then we are done.

Comment: With a quantification/justification of "for large enough $n$", this would be a complete (and rather good) answer. Say, $n\geqslant5$...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Did and Guest both pointed out to me that trying to apply L'Hopital's to discrete cases is only proper when done so more rigorously than was initially shown.

You can think about this as a limit problem and simply use L'Hopital's Rule's when we relate our original sequence to a function:
$$
f(x) = {x \over 2^x}
$$

What you have is $$
\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} {x \over 2^x} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}.
$$

Take the derivative of the numerator and denominator separately and you'll end up with $$
\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} {1 \over log(2)2^x} = 0.
$$

This states that our original sequence will converge to $0$ because the limit of the sequence defined as a function went to $0.$

Comment: If I follow your argument, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi n)=-\infty$ since it is equal, by L'Hôpital's rule, to $-\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}2\pi n^2$ ?

Comment: The discrete analog of L'Hôpital's rule you could use here is [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). What you get is that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: It feels rather odd to see that L'Hopital (involving differentability and even, some never checked hypotheses on the functions involved) is considered as "simple" to solve a question about *sequences*.

Comment: Wow. You're so right. I have naïvely used this idea without even realizing my error through an entire course on analysis. I'm glad you pointed this out to force me to figure out such a big gap in my understanding.

Comment: @Did as an honest question from somebody still new to MSE, would this answer be better off just being deleted, as the original idea behind the answer is incorrect?

Comment: A better option would be to put it into context. Invoking L'H as a simpler approach is, as I said, somewhat odd (invoking Grothendieck's schemes to explain why the sum of two odd integers is even, if you like), but you might present it as an alternative approach (*if suitably justified*, so... what are the hypotheses of L'H already?).

Comment: ((Note that @Guest did not say your approach is "incorrect". And I only mentioned that 1. it is odd and 2. it needs to be completed.))

Comment: Well, an incomplete answer is as incorrect as a wrong answer... for me, seeing my alternative seems easier, since I'm much more comfortable with calculus ideas than I am with analysis. But I see what you mean by it being somewhat unusual. L'Hopitals is only going to work if we have two functions on an open interval, differentiable everywhere except perhaps at the limit we are trying to evaluate. Obviously a sequence is not defined on an open interval.